Maximum Capacity of a Communication Channel w.r.t. $P(Y | X)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are discrete
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two discrete stochastic variables. I want to find $P(Y|X)$ that maximizes the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$, i.e.,
$$\max_{P(Y|X)} I(X, Y).$$
This problem is different from the one in the Boyd and Vandenberghe, Convex Optimization, exercise 4.57 pages 207-8, since I do not want to optimize for $P(X)$ but rather for $P(Y | X)$.
To my understanding, the problem is convex in $P(Y | X)$. I am not aware of how to find an analytical solution to the problem.
Furthermore, this problem looks underdefined, since there are multiple solutions that satisfy the problem. In fact, we can consider $Y$ to be a binary variable, and see that if $P^*(Y | X)$ is an optimal solution, then $\tilde{P}(Y| X) = 1 - P^*(Y | X)$ is also an optimal solution (i.e., flipping the probability of $P^*(Y=1|X)$ and $P^*(Y=0 | X)$).
I wonder if that is a main issue, and maybe there is a technique to define group of equivalences for all $P(Y | X)$ that have the same mutual information in the problem, and there is a possibility of finding a canonical representation of $P(Y | X)$ so to reduce the number of parameters.
To summarize, my questions are the following:

Is there an analytical solution of the maximum channel capacity w.r.t. $P(Y |X)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are discrete variables? If yes what is it? There are some references I can look in to?

Is there a way to get rid of the redundancy of $P(Y | X)$ (i.e., find a class of equivalence of the optimal solutions)?



Just a terminology thing: a maximisation program is usually called convex if its objective is a concave function of the decision variables. In your case, the opposite is true, and the program is thus nonconvex. This naturally leads to the issues of multiple optima, usually lying on the boundary of the domain. It can often get quite hard to solve these programs analytically, and not just because there are multiple solutions, although numerically the fact that there will be many local maxima is definitely an issue.

The problem itself, however, is well defined, barring that you did not explicitly specify the set that $Y$ takes values in. Presumably this is  a fixed finite set?

Hi, thanks for your clarification. The set X and Y, are both discrete and finite (although they can be different sets).
